# How to avoid blurry png export of pandas dataframe using dfi.export() or other method?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export, png, blurry

Does anybody know how to export your styled panda dataframe as a png file with a non-blurry result. Here is my code, which leads to the following image:

```
dfi.export(df1, 'df1.png')
```

I guess I am looking for a parallel to dpi, which is used to increase the sharpness when saving a figure as png.

```
plt.savefig('fig1.png', dpi=1200)
```

Blurry export:

[image]